# php mysql query result array and foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

Any one have idea how to do the following:

I have the following mysql query :

client 1026 has two clients under him: 1056 (on the left ) & 1497 ( on the right )
and each of client 1056 and client 1497 has two other clients under them, and so on

now i want to make a loop to collect all the clients under the client 1026

i have this mysql query

```
$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='1026'";
$res = mysql_query($sql_query);
$ids=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
    $ids[]=$row->id;
}
$ids=array_filter($ids);
foreach($ids as $id){
    echo $id;
    echo '<br>';
    $sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $ids=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
        $ids[]=$row->id;
    }
    $ids=array_filter($ids);
    foreach($ids as $id){
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

it return

1056

106410801497

15051521

now how can i make this query get array result ( like 1056,1497 ) and then use foreach loop  to get the result and the result of the result of the result etc.. until there is no more result?

You can use mysql , mysqli , PDO all i want is to accomplish the request

Comment: So why aren't you using `mysql_fetch_array()`?

Comment: @EisaAdil - what's wrong with mysql_fetch_object?

Comment: If you've got an arbitrarily deep tree, then the only way I can think of to do what you want is through recursion - you'll need to get a client's sub-clients; then check if any of those have their own sub-clients, and so on.

Comment: andrewsi , how to do that :D ?

Comment: @user3117183 - the standard way would be to create a function that takes a client's ID as the parameter; that queries for sub-clients of that client. If there are any, it calls itself, passing in each sub-client's ID in turn.

Comment: andrewsi, can you give example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ids=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
ids[]=$row->id;
 }
$ids=array_filter($ids);
/*To remove empty array*/
foreach($ids as $id){
echo $id;
 }
```

Comment: ok now how can we do the foreach loop ?to look for the clients under each  client id?

Comment: foreach($ids as $id){}

Comment: look define a array variable first .Then store each element in that array. Then loop through foreach ok